# how to copy one folder to all other folders with batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy folder `IMAGE` to all other folders in a folder.

The folder structure is:

- **Test folder**

  - FirstSubFolder
  - **IMAGE**
  - OneMoreSubFolder
  - Test Folder 1
  - TestFolder2

The result should be:

- **Test folder**

  - FirstSubFolder

    - **IMAGE**
  - **IMAGE**
  - OneMoreSubFolder

    - **IMAGE**
  - Test Folder 1

    - **IMAGE**
  - TestFolder2

    - **IMAGE**

Which commands do I need in a batch script to do this folder copying task?

Comment: This is not a question but something like a task request; please show us what you have tried so far and tell us what you you have problems with...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
FOR /D %%G in ("./*") DO IF NOT "%%G"=="IMAGE" XCOPY "IMAGE" "%%G/IMAGE" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y
```

Comment: Did my solution work? If not you can tell me what's still going wrong and I can help you with that but if it did you should mark it as correct by clicking the check to the left of it.